# angular-ui-router generated two ui-views

Tags: angular-ui-router

I use angular-ui-router for routing pages. The problem is like the title of this. The first ui-view displays the page normally. the second ui-view display
the first loaded page and unchanged. I don't want to display second one.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test').config(['$stateProvider', 
                                      '$urlRouterProvider',  
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     // For unmatched routes
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // Application routes
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
        })
```

---

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="RedCA">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>RedCA Admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/bootstrap-3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script> -->
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>



    <!-- Ace settings handler -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/ace.min/js/ace-extra.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ace Script -->
    <script src="components/ace.min/js/ace-elements.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/ace.min/js/ace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ace Styles -->
<!--     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/ace.min/css/ace-fonts.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/ace.min/css/ace.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/ace.min/css/ace-rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/ace.min/css/ace-skins.min.css"/> -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/routingConfig-thirdparty.js"></script>      <!-- app controller side --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/st-openpms.concat.js"></script>      <!-- app controller side -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard.min.js"></script> <!-- rdash augular ui -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="openpms-st-test.templates.js"></script> <!-- openpms st -->


</head>
<body ng-controller="redcaCtrl">
  <div id="page-wrapper" ng-class="{'open': toggle}" ng-cloak>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar">
        <li class="sidebar-main">
          <a ng-click="toggleSidebar()">
            Dashboard
            <span class="menu-icon glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-title"><span>NAVIGATION</span></li>
        <li class="sidebar-list">
          <a href="#">Dashboard <span class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar-list">
          <a href="#/tables">Tables <span class="menu-icon fa fa-table"></span></a>
        </li>
       <!--  <li class="sidebar-list">
          <a href="#/test">Test <span class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></span></a>
        </li> -->

        <li class="sidebar-title"><span>Demonstration</span></li>

                    <li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a
                    href="#/demo">Demo Page</a></li>

        <!-- ///smart town  
                {{DOC_BASE}} -> # -->

                <li class="sidebar-title"><span>SmartTown Sample</span></li>
                <br>

                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#/selectProject">Select Project</a> </li>-->
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/mainMenu">Main Menu</a></li>
                <!--<li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/chat">Chat</a></li>-->
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/chatMulti">ChatMulti</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/noti">Noti</a></li>
                <!--<li data-access-level="accessLevels.anon" active-nav><a href="#/login">Log in</a></li>-->
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.anon" active-nav><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a
                    href="#/picload">Comm Pic</a></li>
                <!--<li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a href="#/crud">CRUD sample</a></li>-->
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a
                    href="#/comm">Comm</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a
                    href="#/punchlist">Punch</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a
                    href="#/register">Register</a></li>
                <!--<li data-access-level="accessLevels.user" active-nav><a href="#/private">Private</a></li>-->
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin" active-nav><a
                    href="#/admin">Admin</a></li>
                <li data-access-level="accessLevels.user"><a href="" data-ng-click="logout()">Log out</a></li>
<!-- ///smart town  -->        


      </ul>
      <div class="sidebar-footer">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <a href="https://github.com/rdash/rdash-angular" target="_blank">
            Github
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <a href="https://github.com/rdash/rdash-angular/README.md" target="_blank">
            About
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <a href="#">
            Support
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Sidebar -->

    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div class="page-content">

        <!-- Header Bar -->
        <div class="row header">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="user pull-right">
              <div class="item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                  <img src="img/avatar.jpg">
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">
                    Joe Bloggs
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">
                      Profile
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">
                      Menu Item
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">
                      Menu Item
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">
                      Logout
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="item dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                  <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                  <li class="dropdown-header">
                    Notifications
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Server Down!</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="meta">
              <div class="page">
                Dashboard
              </div>
              <div class="breadcrumb-links">
                Redca Administration
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Header Bar -->

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div ui-view></div>

      </div><!-- End Page Content -->
    </div><!-- End Content Wrapper -->
  </div><!-- End Page Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call .otherwise on $routeProvider:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/a.html', 
      controller: 'ctrlA'
    })
    .when('/b/:tagId', {
      templateUrl: '/b.html', 
      controller:  'ctrlB'
    })
    .when('/another', {
      templateUrl: '/another.html', 
      controller:  'ctrlC'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```